# wc_get_products() return empty object

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api, api

I'm trying to get all the products that exists in database, but my code return empty objects.
just for the sake of testing, first I'm trying to get only 10 products,
here is my code

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'getProducts');
function getProducts()
{
    register_rest_route('products/v1/', 'allproducts', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'allProducts',
    ));
}
function allProducts()
{
    $products = wc_get_products(array(
        'limit' => 10
    ));
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: The code looks ok. Have you tested allProducts outside of the rest call to see if it works on its own? What do you mean the code returns 'empty objects' ?

Comment: yes of course, I'm testing with postman

Comment: `wc_get_products()` probably returns WC_Product objects, which can’t be turned into JSON, which means that returning them directly wouldn’t work.

Comment: what can I do to make it return the actual products ?
Or can it be caused by a wrong hook ?